# how to use scroll function in dynamically data is coming in footer

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have to use scroll function in footer in which data is been stored in button dynamically and that scroll should hide then we scroll it show again and all data and scroll should be dynamically load in footer only window screen should not change only footer will change at time of scroll

in jquery:-

```
 function callXMLConnection() {  

        $.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "url.html",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: "",
                cache:false,
                processData:false,
                crossDomain:true,
                success: processSuccess,

            });

      }


      function processSuccess(data) {

             $(data).find("category").each(function () {

             var id = $(this).find('id').text();
             var title = $(this).find('title').text();
             var scripts = "<a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme='b' data-inline='true'>"+title+"</a>"                
            $("#menu_button1")
             .append(scripts)
             .trigger('create');
         });
      }
   $(document).unbind('ready').bind('ready', function () {
     $("#menu_button1").scroll(function () {
     // if ($("#menu_button1").scrollLeft(300) == $(document).width() - $("#menu_button1").width()) 
     if ($("#menu_button1").scrollHeight - $("#menu_button1").scrollTop() == $("#menu_button1").outerHeight())
     {
       callXMLConnection(); 
   }
});

     });
```

in html5:-

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="scroll_menu" style="overflow: scroll;">
              <div class="menu" id="menu_button1" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you nesting onscroll handler of window object inside scrollFunction() and processData() ? What is create event? BTW, each time you scroll your page, you are making an ajax request? Looks like very very weird

Comment: your question is unclear, please elaborate?

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul the data is coming in footer dynamically. It can be maximum data for that in sequence way is stored in single line for that scroll i want to put the user can scroll and see the data.Take a example of these page only in right hand side a scroll is there to see the bottom data that scroll i need in bottom

Comment: still your question is unclear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the answer of these

In HTML5:-

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home">    
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">        
           <div  class="categories" id="cat">                
              <ul id="cat_list" class="cat_list_class"></ul>               
           </div>
      </div>    
</div>
```

In jquery:-

```
 var step = 1;
 var current = 0;
 var maximum = 0;
 var visible = 2;
 var speed = 500;
 var liSize = 120;
 var height = 60;    
 var ulSize = liSize * maximum;
 var divSize = liSize * visible;

 $(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {    
      callMenuConnection(); 
       $('.categories').css("width", "auto").css("height", height+"px").css("visibility", "visible").css("overflow", "hidden").css("position", "relative");
       $(".categories ul a").css("list-style","none").css("display","inline");
       $(".categories ul").css("width", ulSize+"px").css("left", -(current * liSize)).css("position", "absolute").css("white-space","nowrap").css("margin","0px").css("padding","5px");      
  });

 $(document).unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
        scroll();
 });
   function callMenuConnection() {  
       $.support.cors = true;
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "one.html",
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: "",
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            crossDomain:true,
            success: processSuccess,
            error: processError
        }); 
  }
      var scripts ="";     
  function processSuccess(data) {
         $(data).find("category").each(function () {     
         var id = $(this).find('id').text();
         var title = $(this).find('title').text();
          scripts = scripts+'<a  class="ids_cat" data-role="button" data-transition="slide"  data-inline="true" >' +title+ '</a>';
        });
        $('#cat_list').append(scripts);
        $('#cat_list').trigger('create');
         maximum = $(".categories ul a").size();
  }

     function processError(data)
       {
           alert("error");
       }

 function scroll(){ 
 $(".categories").swipeleft(function(event){
  if(current + step < 0 || current + step > maximum - visible) {return; }
else {
    current = current + step;
    $('.categories ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
}
return false;
});

  $(".categories").swiperight(function(event){
    if(current - step < 0 || current - step > maximum - visible) {return; }
        else {
      current = current - step;
       $('.categories ul').animate({left: -(liSize * current)}, speed, null);
    }
   return false;
   });         
 }
```